# Netty 4 - What is the expectation and strategy for connecting out and queuing messages

Tags: netty

When calling clientBootstrap.connect(host, port), if I have lots of requests that can be made to this host/port before the channel is established (ie-if I call channel.write(message)) on this channel before it's connected, then is it expected that:

1) Netty 4 will queue this message internally and that I simply call flush once it's connected?   I had that expectation but is not working for me so want to confirm.  If that's the expectation I could share some code.

OR

2) Is the expectation that I need to track connection state and queue these messages myself and only call writeMessage() myself once I know the connection is established.

OR

3) Other strategy?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not call write before it is connected. If you do so the ChannelFuture will be failed with NotYetConnectedException.

Comment: Thanks Norman.  I confirmed that is exactly what I am seeing so will handle this case at my layer.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is not the same as the above answer in 4.1.0.Beta5 based on my understanding of the code. The write method will not check if the channel is active now, and the check is moved to the flush method.  however, we still cannot write before the channel is registered, as your handlers may not have been added to the pipeline.

I do not know why netty has to be this way, maybe netty can just build up the pipeline in a build() method before connect.  So users can just use netty's internal queue and don't need to create another queue.